# Why should i use Intent to send a string from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a simple doubt. In android it been said almost everywhere that to pass a `String` or `int` or anything u supposed to use `Intent` and use `putextra()` or whatever to pass it over that next `activity` where as i can create a static object and access it from any `activity`

There has to be some reason behind using the intent to do so, can anyone please clear me why we need `intent` to pass an object from one `activity` to other where we can do it as normally as we do it in java.

Comment: Read these articles - [Vogella.de](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents) and [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra)

Comment: have a look at this pdf, you will get to know why not to use `static` http://dubroy.com/memory_management_for_android_apps.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because we don't think of Activities in a static context. Activities have life cycles, so we try to incorporate our data within this life cycle rather than circumventing it.

There's nothing directly wrong with just using a static variable, but there could arise some problems. Say, for instance, you display multiple instances of an `Activity`. The `String` you need for the child `Activity` might be different than what you previously needed, so when navigating backwards to a previous instance of that `Activity`, the value is not what you were expecting.

Passing the `String` in through the `Intent` also makes the `Activity` independent. One `Activity` should not be designed in a way that it is tightly coupled with another. Passing data through the `Intent` means that any `Activity` can start this `Activity` as long as it passes in the correct data.

That said, there are cases where using a statically accessible variable are reasonable, such as for constants values that won't change and are accessed by multiple parts of your app, or for any data that multiple Activities might need.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you *can* use statics to pass data from one `Activity` to another.  That doesn't mean it's the best idea.  Here's a few reasons for using `Intent` **extras**.

1. **It's a convention.**  It's what most Android developers do, and that matters.  If anyone other than you is going to read or maintain your code, it's good to use common solutions to your programming problems.
2. *In general*, in Java, or other OO programming languages, it's preferred to avoid using static variables (unless they're constants).  [Here's one article on why this is](http://www.offthehill.org/articles/2011/06/03/java-static-variables-are-wrong-almost-always/) and [here's another](http://gbracha.blogspot.com/2008/02/cutting-out-static.html).
3. Think about a normal, non-Android application.  Forget about `Activities` and `Intents`.  If you had one controller object that needed to create another controller object, it could use code like this:

FirstController.java:

```java
public void doSomething() {
    SecondController newController = new SecondController();
    newController.start();
}
```

And if you wanted to pass a String variable from the first controller to the second, you wouldn't use static variables ... you'd just do this:

```java
    newController.start("WithSomeData");
```

Now, think about Android again.  `Activity` objects are not instantiated in the same way.  One `Activity` does not simply `new` up another one, hold a reference to it, and get to call its methods.  That's why this rather convoluted process is needed.  Because if `Activity` objects are created indirectly through `Intent` objects, then the "caller" doesn't yet have a reference to the "called" object, and thus can't use normal methods and parameter passing.  So, if we accept this limitation, then you need another way to pass information.  Since the `Intent` object is used to create an `Activity`, or return to an existing `Activity`, it made sense to give `Intents` the ability to handle extra data, like passed parameters.

And again, this solution was created because of a general dislike for using static variables, and the problems with them.

But, if you just have two `Activity` classes, and **there will only ever be one concurrent instance** of each `Activity`, then you could probably get away with static variables.  I still wouldn't recommend it, for the reasons I outlined.

Answer (score 2):

Read Intent definition from [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. In Android Intents are used to activate components(Activity, Service, BroadcastReceivers). You can pass Strings or other data through Static Variables, but its not a good practice, cause in a big application, you have a lot of headache to manage, if you are using static variables.

Also read intents are of two types, implicit intents, and explicit intents, in exlicit intents you can use static variables cause you know target component, but through implicit intents where target components arent specified, Static Variables are not of any use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main reason for using .putExtras() on an intent would be to pass a large object such as a string array between two activities.

None the less I would suggest to create a global class that contains all of your variables that you want to use in multiple activities, it is much simpler to access multiple variables that are all in one place than to try and pass a bunch of variables between activities.

Answer (score 0):

Take it simply, Static variable are supposed to preloaded at load time... so, it will increase the memory use and your processing and if your application didn't execute up to the static variable is use.. it's worthless to preloaded the variables.